# Android: How to change background of ShapeDrawable

Tags: android

I have a problem in the following code.

I want to create a layerlist dramatically. And if I set background of each layer by setColor(int color), it gives me a good result. But now I want to set background by image using drawable. But the result is not what I expected.

```
public LayerDrawable testCreate() {

    ShapeDrawable background = new ShapeDrawable();

    background.getPaint().setStyle(Style.FILL);
    background.getPaint().setColor(R.drawable.progress_background);
            // if using setColor(
    //   getResources().getColor(android.R.color.background_dark)); result will        //be ok



    ShapeDrawable shapeD = new ShapeDrawable();
    shapeD.getPaint().setStyle(Style.FILL);
    shapeD.getPaint().setColor(R.drawable.progress_progress);
    ClipDrawable clipDrawable = new ClipDrawable(shapeD, Gravity.LEFT,
        ClipDrawable.HORIZONTAL);

    LayerDrawable layerDrawable = new LayerDrawable(new Drawable[] {
        clipDrawable, background });
    return layerDrawable;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

use following function to create a `BitmapDrawable`:

```
private BitmapDrawable getDrawable(Resources r, int rId) {
    Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(r, rId);
            //to set height and width call this
    //Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image, height, width, false);
    return new BitmapDrawable(r, image);
}
```

and change your function to:

```
public LayerDrawable testCreate() {

    Drawable background = getDrawable(getResources(),R.drawable.progress_background);

            // if using setColor(android.R.color.background_dark), result will be ok



    Drawable shapeD = getDrawable(getResources(),R.drawable.progress_progress);

    ClipDrawable clipDrawable = new ClipDrawable(shapeD, Gravity.LEFT,
        ClipDrawable.HORIZONTAL);

    LayerDrawable layerDrawable = new LayerDrawable(new Drawable[] {
        clipDrawable, background });
    return layerDrawable;

}
```

Comment: Thanks you very much, i have done because of your help

Comment: don't forget to accept it, if this answer has help you solve your problem ;-)

Answer (score 0):

you call *setColor(`int` color)* with the numeric resource id of the drawable.